# How to build rental ads notifier after parsing website?

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, telegram

Currently I need to find an apartment so I decided to automaticaly parse a website page and send new ads to my telegram.

That's how I thought to do it:

1. Parse this page via apify.com:
   https://www.yad2.co.il/realestate/rent?city=5000&property=1,5,6&rooms=5--1&price=-1-10000&priceOnly=1&imgOnly=1
2. Get an ID and picture preview of every ad.
3. Set a schedule to get data every hour in json. The structure is:

   [{
   "orderId": "uniqueIdOfAd",
   "image": "urlOfImage"
   },
   {
   "orderId": "uniqueIdOfAd",
   "image": "urlOfImage"
   },.... and so on]
4. Write some code in Javascript to make a simple database. The goal is to filter the data (check if this Id already exists in my dtabase) and send new ad (that is not listed in my database) to telegram channel from telegram bot. I already registered a telegram bot and I know that I can use this url to send a message to chanel:
   [https://api.telegram.org/bot[BOT_API_KEY]/sendMessage?chat_id=[MY_CHANNEL_NAME]&text=[MY_MESSAGE_TEXT]](https://api.telegram.org/bot%5BBOT_API_KEY%5D/sendMessage?chat_id=%5BMY_CHANNEL_NAME%5D&text=%5BMY_MESSAGE_TEXT%5D)

---

My problem is in step 4. Help me please to understand where I should build this algorithm. Do I need to do a simple website that requests the URL of new data every hour and handles it? Or it should be something else?
I just started to learn web development, so I stand on some basic level :)

Comment: I guess you could set up a background service so you don't have to pay for a website hosting. What OS do you use?

Comment: I guess in this case my computer have to be on 24/7 right? Actually a have a hosting plan so may be there is a way to do it remotely without my computer?

Comment: It depends what is cheaper for you. Your service doesn't have to run 24/7 because apartment listings usually don't come up at night. If you want to save even more, you can make it run only once or twice per hour. Although hosting cloud functions (not whole websites) can be fairly cheap nowadays. You can look for Google Cloud or Firebase.